# How to use nontype template parameters to pass in a pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-arrays, non-type

This code is part of my implementation of the canoe rental problem in dynamic programming.

I am dynamically allocating a 2-D array on the heap, and saving the returned address into a variable of type pointer to array. The 2-D matrix itself is a perfect N*N square. I am using this unorthodox approach because the array is stored in row-major order for ease of storing it into the cache.

I then want to pass that pointer to array into a function in order to fill in the table. And I am using a nontype template parameter because I may be passing a pointer to a different size array. I don't know the size of the matrix in advance, that is determined by the user's input.

Here is my code. I am using `int8_t` because I know that each of the values in the matrix will be a number < 256.

```
#include <cstdint>   // for uint8_t
#include <cstdlib>   // for size_t, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::vector;


template <size_t num_of_stations>
void fillPrices(uint8_t (*&prices)[num_of_stations])
{

}

int main()
{
    size_t num_of_stations = 0;
    cin >> num_of_stations;

    uint8_t (*prices)[num_of_stations] = static_cast<uint8_t(*)[num_of_stations]>( malloc(sizeof(uint8_t[num_of_stations][num_of_stations])) );

    fillPrices(prices);

    delete[] prices;
    prices = nullptr;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get a compilation error. What should be changed in the code to make it compile?

```
canoe_rental.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
canoe_rental.cpp:32:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘fillPrices(uint8_t (*&)[num_of_stations])’
     fillPrices(prices);
                      ^
canoe_rental.cpp:11:6: note: candidate: template<long unsigned int num_of_stations> void fillPrices(uint8_t (*&)[num_of_stations])
 void fillPrices(uint8_t (*&prices)[num_of_stations])
      ^
canoe_rental.cpp:11:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
canoe_rental.cpp:32:22: note:   variable-sized array type ‘long int’ is not a valid template argument
     fillPrices(prices);
                      ^
```

Comment: If it is C++, why do you use `malloc` and C-style arrays? Why don't you use `std::vector` and `std::array`? You don't need a `template` here at all, because `num_of_stations` is not known at compile time.

Comment: @Evg A vector of vectors would not be in contiguous memory! That is one of the requirements.

Comment: You don't have to use `vector` of `vector`s. If you need contiguous 2D matrix, use simple arithmetic like `pos = i + lead_dim * j`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that nontype template parameters are more trouble than they are worth. So I solved that problem by passing the pointer to array as a `void*` and also passing in the number of elements in the pointed to array, and then just using a type cast. Now inside the body I can use the array as intended. It's a little not elegant, but it works!

```
void fillPrices(void* ptr, size_t num_of_stations)
{
    uint8_t (*prices)[num_of_stations] = static_cast<uint8_t(*)[num_of_stations]>(ptr);

}

// To call the function:
int main() {
    // more code here
    fillPrices(prices, num_of_stations);
}
```

Comment: They are not trouble at all, they just serve different purpose. In your problem `num_of_stations` is a **run-time** variable. It can't be used as a `template` parameter - templates always need **compile-time** constants.

Comment: @Evg I see. Thank you for the info.